# Send voice message using laravel-pusher without twilio

Tags: laravel, twilio, pusher

I'm working on a messenger like telegram or whatsApp but my app is a game.

Players will send their voice messages to group. For some other features I installed [This package](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets) to have broadcasting system and everything is fine.

Now I need to use some kind of `webrtc` but as it's my first experience in that field, I'm not sure how can I handle recorded audio in the server and `stream` that file to other users joined to group using `pusher and laravel echo`!

After some research I found `twilio` but I want to have my own server just like the package mentioned before.

Do you have any suggestion or experience?

***Thanks in advance***